# How to remove a postgresql user

Tags: postgresql

I followed [this tutorial](http://musings.tinbrain.net/simple-django-deploy/) and made a typo where I was supposed to create a user for my django apps to connect as;

I was supposed to run `su - postgres -c "createuser www-data -P"` but I ran `su - postgres -c "createuser www-dtata -P"`.

I dont want to proceed until I remove that user, which I don't know the command for. I found and tried `DROP USER` after searching around, but the terminal returned `-su: DROP: command not found`.

Comment: `drop user` is a **SQL** command. You need to run it through a SQL tool, not from the Linux command line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run `sudo su - postgres -c "dropuser www-dtata"`

Comment: asks for a password and when i enter the one i used to create that user it says `authentication failure`. Tried with a blank password too, same outcome

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dropuser` console tool (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-dropuser.html):

```
su - postgres -c "dropuser www-dtata"
```

Or use `DROP USER` SQL query (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-dropuser.html):

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c 'DROP USER "www-dtata";'
```

These 2 approaches do the same thing. In SQL version, you also need to use double quotes around DB user name, due to `-` in it.

Answer (score -1):

## First run the command

sudo su

## Enter the user password for root access.

## Then run the below command

su - postgres -c "dropuser www-dtata"

## No password will be prompted

Comment: This is basically repeating the the solution provided by Vasyl Moskalov in 2017. How does this add value to the OP's question?